# Trig substitution in the definite integral $\int_1^2 x \sqrt{1 - x^2} dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have the following integral

$$\int_1^2 x \sqrt{1 - x^2}\, \mathrm dx$$

I want to use the trig substitution $x = \sin \theta$ but I can't because the limits of integration do not permit such a substitution.

So I tried $x = \sin\theta + 1$ but this does not seem to help. So I am left wondering: Is there a smart way to use a trig substitution here or should I try an other path?

Comment: As the integral will evaluate to a complex number anyway, you might want to use the complex sine function, which does have a solution to $\sin z = 2$. Assuming that your integrand doesn't have a typo, perhaps its meant to be real?

Comment: You note that the radicand of your integrand runs into trouble?

Comment: $\sin^{-1} 2$ is complex.  But with those limits of integration, you are going to get a complex answer anyway.  So, go ahead and use $x =\sin t.$  But how about  $u = 1-x^2, du = -2x dx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple way**

There is a simple way to calculate this integral:
$$
F(x) = \int x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int(1-x^2)^{1/2}dx^2 = -\frac{1}{3}(1-x^2)^{3/2} + C.
$$
Then as $\int_1^2x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx = F(2) - F(1)$ we have 
$$
\int_1^2 x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx = -\frac{1}{3}(1 - 2^2)^{3/2} = i\sqrt{3}.
$$

**Using trig substitution**

If you want to use exactly trig substitution $x = \sin\vartheta$, you will have
$$
F(x) = \int\sin\vartheta\cos\vartheta \;d\sin\vartheta = -\int \cos^2\vartheta\;d\cos\vartheta = -\frac{1}{3}\cos^3\vartheta + C = -\frac{1}{3}\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^3 + C,
$$
which is the same, of cource. But if you want to use trig substitution in definite integral you will need to calculate $\arcsin(2)$. To do this you need to represent $\arcsin$ function as $\arcsin(x) = i\ln(ix + \sqrt{1 - x^2})$ (using [inverse hyperbolic sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_function#Inverse_hyperbolic_sine) function). In our case we have
$$
\arcsin(2) = i\ln\left((2+\sqrt{3})i\right).
$$
To calculate the answer we need to represent $\cos$ function using [hyperbolic cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_analytic_expressions) function as $\cos x = (e^{ix} + e^{-ix})/2$.

Summing up, we get the same result
$$
\int_1^2 x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx = -\int_{\pi/2}^{i\ln\left((2+\sqrt{3})i\right)}\cos^2\vartheta\;d\cos\vartheta = -\frac{1}{3}\cos^3\left(i\ln\left((2+\sqrt{3})i\right)\right) = i\sqrt{3}
$$
as
$$
\cos\left(i\ln\left((2+\sqrt{3})i\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{\ln((2 + \sqrt{3})i)} + e^{-\ln((2 + \sqrt{3})i)}\right) = \frac{i}{2}\left(2 + \sqrt{3} - \frac{1}{2 + \sqrt{3}}\right) = i\sqrt{3}.
$$